# Objective-C SpriteKit: What is the relation between values set in CGVector and actual International System of Units (SI)?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, physics

In Apple Developer's Guide, it says:

> Sprite Kit uses the International System of Units, also known as SI,
>   or the meter-kilogram-second system. Where necessary, you may need to
>   consult other reference materials online to learn more about the
>   physics equations used by [**Sprite
>   Kit**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html)

I am developing a little game with a bat that swings his wings when user touches the screen. For the main menu, I want my bat to keep flying up and down, describing an harmonic oscillation, like in [this video 01:43 to 01:46](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZ541Luq4nE&t=1m42s)

Code

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)createBat:(float)scale {
    SKSpriteNode *bat = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bat_01"];
    bat.xScale = scale;
    bat.yScale = scale;
    bat.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bat.size];
    return bat;
}

-(SKAction *)actionSwingWings {
    return [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self.player.physicsBody setVelocity: CGVectorMake(0.0f, 450.0f)];
    }];
}

-(float)timeToReturnToInitialPositionAfterJump {
    /* CODE SUPPRESSED TO SPARE CHARACTERS
    ORIGINAL CODE CALCULATES BHASKARA WITH a=gravity/2, b=initSpeed=450.0 & c=0
    c=0 because I want my bat to swing wings again when he falls back to the last wing swing position
    The bhaskara function is tested and returning the correct values */
}

-(SKAction *)actionStationaryFly {
    return [SKAction repeatActionForever:
            [SKAction sequence:@[
                [self actionSwingWings],
                [SKAction waitForDuration:[self timeToReturnToInitialPositionAfterJump]]
            ]]
    ];
}
```

Problem

The main idea is to use the Bhaskara function to know how much time the bird must wait between each wing swing, but its not working. I checked the calculations and bhaskara function is consistent. The bat behavior, in the other hand, is not.

I choose Bhaskara for this application because positionChange = initialSpeed*time + 0.5*speedUp*time*time, as physics tells us in formula. When positionChange=0 and time>0, I should get the wing swing interval.

For the current values:
gravity=-9.8;
initialVelocity=450;
My Bhaskara returns 91.8, while the bat shows the desired behavior only when I set the time between wing swings to 0.6 (one wing swing for each 0.6 seconds).

Why does the system behave like that? If the CGVectors represented the SI as Apple says, shouldn't the actual bat behavior be consistent with the calculations made based on it's speed and speedup?

Comment: I suggest you applyImpulse to the physicsBody of your sprite instead of setting its velocity.

Comment: physics engine != real-world physics ... (not all) physics formulas can be applied to a physics engine

Comment: @CodeMonkey, my first approach was with applyImpulse, but I want all my wing swings to get the bat to fly up with the same speed. With applyImpulse, the bat speed get doubled if the users touches 2 times in a short period of time. I want the speed of the bat to be the same, no matter if the user touched one time or many times in a row. To use applyImpulse, I would have to setVelocity to zero first everytime I wanted the bat to swing his wings!

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that information clarifies things a little bit, thanks!

Comment: You can add wind resistance to your bat (via the linearDamping property of its physicsBody) to make the sim more realistic. Also, applying an impulse to the bat is closer to real life than setting the velocity. You can temporarily disable touches for a set period after applying the impulse.